# Manage SVN hooks with SVN?

Tags: svn, hook, svn-hooks

As far as I could see, there is no built-in feature to manage SVN hooks in SVN itself. There are some ideas of course, such as another repository with hooks scripts, running an `svn export` to the `hooks` directory on commit, but how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got hooks managed by SVN in one of my repositories. This is not the same repository though; I've created second SVN repository to hold hooks for the first one. I was worried about breaking access to the main repo with a faulty commit.

Comment: By fault commit, do you mean an error in a hook script that prevents commmit access to the repository? I've sidestepped the worry about breaking commit access to the main repository with an error in a hook script by skipping all policies in the hook script for one superuser.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing wrong with making the hooks directory a subversion checkout. So after committing the hook, you merely have to `svn up` in the hooks directory, as the post-commit action.

I think it should also work to make the hooks directory a checkout of the very repository it is managing.